# Controls access binding properties but don't display

Tags: c#, data-binding, maui

##### Context:

In .Net Maui with Community Tool Kit MVVM

I have a working binding where a `CollectionView` updates its items according to the items on the `ObservableCollection`

Viewmodel:

```cs
[ObservableProperty] ObservableCollection<ProductModel> items;
```

And on the c# backing file for the view:

```cs
//binding is the viewmodel
CollectionView AddList()
{
    CollectionView list = new()
    {
        ItemsSource = binding.Items,
    (...)
```

##### Issue:

I want to separate products by shops so I started with this:

```cs
[ObservableProperty] Dictionary<ShopModel, ObservableCollection<ShopProductModel>> items;
```

In the the view c# page:

```cs
ItemsSource = binding.Items[shop]
```

Now I am binding to the `ObservableCollection` value and there is no update on the `CollectionView`.

> When debugging **if I refresh manually** I see that the product `item` becomes an item on the `CollectionView` but it doesnt show on the screen only on the debug dropdown.

Comment: why don't you just use [grouping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/grouping)?

Comment: wasn't aware it was an option, it seems that is exactly what I look for, or close, it seems I can only group vertically, is there a way to display the groups side by side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

The code Shown worked all along the issue was in one command that needed one parameter of the wrong type and so the binding crashed.

All I had to do was to change:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
void Delete(ProductModel p)
```

To:

```cs
[RelayCommand]
void Delete(ShopProductModel p)
```

So **its ok to Bind to `ObservableCollections` in `Dictionary`**!

Note: I Wondered if I should delete the post but reading on [SO Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349818/14694660) I believe this can stay for posterity.

Comment: Yes I agree with you. If you don't pass the correct parameter, the command will not execute. However, your question seems not too much related with your answer. We even don't realize there's a command to update/delete the item.

Comment: That's because at first I didn't realize this was the issue, but the question is not about executing commands, its about bindings. And I hope the mention at the end reveals that the bindings are actually working but with issues, and the answer reveals a possible issue (in my case The issue). If you have a more thorough answer I can happily support it

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do here.. I would love to learn more but this question on my end is solved, I had an issue and I found it, now its working. If you think there's a better answer please do it, I believe the binding issue could happen in other scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to aproach this filling out a List object and then fill your Collection. This applies if you are retrieving data from an API or if you have your data stored locally.

XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate models:ProductModel>
                  your design...
                 </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView >
```

Where: {Binding Products} is the name of your ObservableCollection in your viewmodel and ProductModel is a class of your model containing the properties that you want.

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<ProductModel> Products { get; set; } = new();
```

And then you only need to fill the Collection with:

```
Products.Add(new ProductModel()
{
  Properties...
});
```

You may use a foreach of your List to get the objects to fill the Collection.

If you have your data in a Dictionary, you can use this to convert it to a list:

```
list = dic.Keys.ToList();
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue. this is a simple binding to a list, I mentioned I have that working what I need is to bind to a value in a dictionary or something that allows me to have an undetermined amount of lists (one per shop and I don't know how many shops at compile time)